# 18.04.2 Wifi crashes and system freezes

Tags: wireless, freeze, crash

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 alongside windows 10 on my XPS13 (9380) and I am having problems with the wifi where it sometimes disconnects and when I go into the settings it doesn't show any of the wifi options and to contact my software vendor. I have tried updating to the latest kernel and the latest wifi driver (my wifi module is the Qualcomm QCA6174), restarting the network-manager, disabling wifi power saving. If I don't try to turn the wifi off the system behaves almost normally, except any sudo commands hang (do not ask for the password). Trying to turn the wifi off results in the system freezing and becoming completely unresponsive (can only be hard reset, alt+prtscr+REISUB does not work). After being reset it continues to work without any issues until the wifi disconnects again (this happened as often as every hour to as rarely as once a day).
Any suggestions on how to fix or debug this? Using ubuntu has become basically impossible, thank you for any suggestions.

EDIT:
I have tried updating the firmware as suggested in other posts, and updating the kernel again, but the wifi remains unstable. Apparently the wifi card (QCA6174) does not have a great reputation but it being soldered onto the motherboard there is not much I can do about it.
Dell sells this same laptop (same hardware) with ubuntu pre installed, so they must have tested it for stability. If anyone has the Developer edition of the dell XPS 13 (9380) could they tell me what ath10k driver and kernel version the system was running out of the box? Thank you

Comment: For the reset issue, try Ctrl+Alt+PrntScr+REISUB

Comment: I suggested a possible duplicate - if you search AskUbuntu for "qca6174" you will find that several people have found that updating the firmware files for the device fixes the problem.